# Refresh Jquery UI dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Basically, I've loaded in content to a container from another page using:

```
$('#profile').load('/_profile #rightSection');
```

So it's pulling information dynamically which works great, basically the UI isn't adding the theme to this new content and I'm sure it's got something to do with the fact that they're being pulled from another page (yet local).

This is how I'm calling my UI buttons:

```
$('button, input[type="submit"]').button();
$('input[type="text"], input[type=email]').button().addClass('my-textfield');
```

If anyone has any idea on this, it would be awesome to know how to resolve my problem. 
Kind regards, 
Shannon

Comment: When are calling the UI buttons? They should be called once they're in the DOM, i.e. when the load is finished.

Comment: they're being called on document ready @greener

Comment: I have tried this to refresh the new content: 

`$(window).load(function(){
    $('#profile').find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).button().refresh();
    });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a callback on the `.load` and set the buttons then.

```
$('#profile').load('/_profile #rightSection', function() {
  $('button, input[type="submit"]').button();
  $('input[type="text"], input[type=email]').button().addClass('my-textfield');
});
```